# 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list' Have you called 'sort' on a list? with knn.cv

Tags: r, compiler-errors, cross-validation, knn

I am not sure why i am getting this error, I am trying to run cross validation with knn..

which I do as such

```
knn.cv(trainingDigit,label,k=1)
```

My trainingDigit consist of

```
str(trainingDigit)
    List of 10
     $ : num [1:400, 1:324] 1 1 0.969 1 0.992 ...
     $ : num [1:400, 1:324] 1 1 1 1 0.831 ...
     $ : num [1:400, 1:324] 1 1 0.98 1 0.996 ...
     $ : num [1:400, 1:324] 1 1 1 1 1 ...
     $ : num [1:400, 1:324] 0.992 1 1 1 1 ...
     $ : num [1:400, 1:324] 0.961 1 1 1 1 ...
     $ : num [1:400, 1:324] 1 0.957 0.961 0.973 0.988 ...
     $ : num [1:400, 1:324] 1 1 1 1 0.937 ...
     $ : num [1:400, 1:324] 1 0.949 0.988 1 1 ...
     $ : num [1:400, 1:324] 1 1 1 0.984 1 ...
```

Basically just data.. and label contains

```
str(label)
List of 10
     $ : num [1:400] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
     $ : num [1:400] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
     $ : num [1:401] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
     $ : num [1:400] 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
     $ : num [1:400] 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 ...
     $ : num [1:400] 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 ...
     $ : num [1:400] 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 ...
     $ : num [1:400] 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 ...
     $ : num [1:400] 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 ...
     $ : num [1:400] 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 ...
```

Labeling eas list in trainingDigit.. But when i run it I get this error

```
'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'
Have you called 'sort' on a list?
```

I am not sure i understand why, and what it means.. Could somebody clarify what it means ? what i have to do to fix it?

Comment: getting a error message 

`error in match.fun(FUN) : object 'knn.cv' could not be found.`

Comment: thanks for quick response though :)

Comment: I am not sure.. where i you heading at.  what is the purpose of lapply? what should i use it for?

Comment: I am not sure what is missing to make it reproducible..  I won't  post all the data elements as it would just contain a lot of data.

Comment: ohh..  you added the `cl` which the first post didn't

Comment: adding `cl` i get this error 

error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 'train' and 'class' have different lengths

Comment: but ... 

`> length(label)
[1] 10
> length(trainingDigit)
[1] 10`

Comment: Okay so `label` is also a `list`

Comment: yes.. a list of lists..

Comment: The 3rd element in `label` has 401 elements.

Comment: Damn.. I didn't notice that at all.. Map works now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `Map` to apply the `knn.cv` function on the corresponding elements of the two `list`s.

```
Map(function(x,y) knn.cv(x, y, k=1), trainingDigit, label)
```

We can also use the `MoreArgs` argument and remove the anonymous function call.

```
Map(knn.cv, trainingDigit, label, MoreArgs = list(k=1, prob=TRUE))
```